# Jquery and Bootstrap Button value issue

Tags: jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

HTML code

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.repDD.Type)
<button type="button" value="false" onclick="$('#CatD').hide();" class="btn@((!Model.repDD.Type) ? " active" : string.Empty )" data-toggle="button">blah1</button>
```

Jquery

```
@section js {
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {            
           if (!$('#repDD_Type').attr('checked')) {
               $('#CatD').show();
           }
           else {
           $('#CatD').hide();
           }
       });
    </script>
}
```

Basically I'm trying to hide some divs based on the value of the button value which is passed to the page as it's an edit page, but no matter what value it is the present code always shows the div even when it shouldn't and using .val('true') or .val(true) doesn't work either so has anybody encountered this problem with using bootstrap radiobuttons before, as normal radiobuttons aren't affected.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log($('#repDD_Type').attr('checked'));` ?

Comment: @Spin0us nope but have no clue how I can use it either so looking up at what it does but so far I've no clue how I can use it to solve the problem.

Comment: So try with a simple `alert($('#repDD_Type').attr('checked'));`. Could you give more code including the part with your #repDD_Type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap buttons seem to require different standards and in this case I had to do,

```
if ($('#repDD_Type').val() == 'True')
```

as anything else isn't accepted.